# The target “ResolveWebJobFiles” does not exist in the project in Azure Website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, msbuild, azure-webjobs

I have a Windows Azure project consisting of

- ASP.NET project (using NancyFX) deployed as Azure Website
- Business Logic class library
- Unit test class library
- 2 Console apps

I want those 2 console app to be deployed as Azure WebJobs with the Azure Website. So I right clikec on the ASP.NET project and chose Add | Existing project as Azure WebJob and added both console apps with the right schedule.

Everything seems fine, the 2 console apps now contain a JSON with schedule and the ASP.NET project contains a JSON with WebJobs definition. All the project build just fine.

The problem is, when I try to deploy the ASP.NET project to Azure, I get

```
The target “ResolveWebJobFiles” does not exist in the project
```

I found [this article](http://www.tomeggington.co.uk/resolving-the-target-resolvewebjobfiles-does-not-exist-in-the-project/) when the author solved this problem by adding

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.2\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.2\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```

to his csproj file, but my csproj file for the ASP.NET project already contains this import.

Any ideas what the problem is?

Comment: Check if your project have a reference to the WebJob assemblies (Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs + Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host) if not you can add them using nuget package "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs"

Comment: The `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` package was download from Nuget and referenced automatically when adding the webjobs

Comment: same issue after updating to 1.0.3

Comment: What resolved this for me was to install the 'Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish' Nuget package in the web job projects themselves (i.e. the console apps). I had installed this Nuget package in the ASP.NET project, but it appears to be needed in both (or at least the web job projects).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

even i faced this issue. I reinstalled the below package in my webjob to solve it

package id="Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish" version="1.0.2"

Comment: Thanks mate! A simple reinstall (uninstall and install) of this package on the WebJob project did the trick. It could be caused by moving the WebJob from one directory to another.

Comment: @Santosh This is interesting, I've only ever had this package installed in the web app, never in the webjob, and all my webjobs deploy with the web apps they're associated with.

Answer (score 7):

Check to see if you have this file in your webjob project Properties folder:
webjob-publish-settings.json

If not, create it with this content, changing only the webJobName (for now)

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
  "webJobName": "MyWebJobName",
  "startTime": "2014-12-09T00:00:00-08:00",
  "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Hour",
  "interval": 1,
  "runMode": "Scheduled",
  "stopping_wait_time": 3600
}
```

Answer (score 7):

One primary reason could be missing "webjob-publish-settings.json" file in Properties.

Please double check this file exists and included in your project.

Comment: Yep, exactly this. I'd done it in the other 5 jobs and failed to put it here.

Answer (score 5):

in my case it was this file, which had 1 invalid webjob associated with it, removed it and it started working

**webjobs-list.json**

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this. After updating all packages in my solution I started to get this. The `<import />` was there but it was poiting to a different version. So check that too.

Comment: This was the problem for me, the import in my web project (not the webjob) was pointing to the webjob's old location

Answer (score 2):

Also worth checking is the .net version of the WebJob project vs your Web app!

Answer (score 2):

As stated in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/websites-dotnet-deploy-webjobs)

> A WebJobs-enabled project has the following items added to it:
>   - The Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish NuGet package.
>   - A webjob-publish-settings.json file that contains deployment and scheduler settings.

it clearly says the project that needs to have a reference to `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` Nuget package is the Webjob-enabled project application, not the web application. The web application only needs `webjobs-list.json` file.

The webjob console application also may have a `webjob-publish-settings.json` file
but only in case of non continuous jobs

Comment: My continuous WebJob would not deploy without ```webjob-publish-settings.json``` either.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error recently and found the cause to be that [WebProject]/Properties/webjobs-list.json contained a reference to an old webjob that had been deleted from the solution.  Deleting the reference from the json fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Kudu (under "Advanced Tools" on your web app management page, under "Development Tools"), under "Debug console", select "Powershell", then navigate to the "site" folder, then the "repository" folder.

Enter the command "dotnet restore" at the command line, then redeploy.

Edit: Still works as of 26/01/2022.